# How to have multiple headers for different users of Wordpress site

Tags: php

I’ve a created WordPress membership site using wishlist member plugin. But I want to have different header.php based on different logins.

Eg: Users are: Print, Web and Free

- When Free user logs in – I want header1.php to load and stay till he logs out
- When Print user logs in – I want header2.php to load and stay till he logs out
- When Web user logs in – I want header3.php to load and stay till he logs out

If nobody has logged in the default header.php stays.

Please assist on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a include, in the place of the header include this code be aware to edit the name of the variable $userType:

```
switch($userType)
{
case "free": { include("header1.php"); break;}
case "Print": { include("header2.php"); break;}
case "Web": {include("header3.php"); break;}
default: {include('header.php'); break; //nobody logged in 
}
}
```

Comment: How to check, who has logged in? what should be put for $usertype - is the membershiplevel or level ids? I'm a newbie and trying out a project of a membership site. Please assist.